# is my question really unclear?

Tags: discussion

[How do people check or trust money system, that central bank or something else is not cheating?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/29390/how-do-people-check-or-trust-money-system-that-central-bank-or-something-else-i)

> put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Fizz, Bayesian, Adam
>   Bailey, Maarten Punt, VicAche Jun 11 at 17:50

while Brian Romanchuk has understood my question and has answered to it.

so, how my question can be "unclear"? i do not agree with this word.

Answer (score 5):

Although people may choose to answer vague questions, it does not mean the question is clear. It may mean they are choosing to make assumptions about what part you are asking about. For your particular question that you posted, when I read it, the first thing that comes to mind is that you have referred to the broad topic of all of money and banking as just this "money system." In your question, you ask about how to tell if the central bank is "cheating". From this there are two problems for me in trying to answer this question:

1.) Because you only have this idea of the monetary system as this monolithic whole, an answer has to break down the question to address different parts in the system where this "cheating" could happen.

2.) I don't have a good idea of what you consider "cheating", so it is not clear how I might address your particular concerns.

---

Later in the question you do find a narrower question that can possibly be answered, that is, what prevents arbitrary money creation for the self-enrichment of individuals. I think at the least it would have been better to make just that your question, because your other question about the entirety of the monetary system is, at best, too broad to answer. I would have casted a vote either for the question being **too broad** or **unclear**.

I would suggest trying to edit your question down to a smaller scope. Even in Brian's answer, it is clear that you still have a lot of other questions that stem from his answer, and it would be better if Brian's answer could have addressed more of your concerns from the start. If you need help editing your question, maybe another moderator would be willing to give feedback in addition to mine.